# How does eXtremeDB optimize for time series?

Tags: database, time-series, embedded-database

I'm trying to understand how **eXtremeDB** optimizes for time series. The [official documentation](https://www.mcobject.com/docs/Content/Programming/SQL/DDL_Statements/Create_Table.htm) mentions the use of the `SEQUENCE` data type. When defining a column of this type, one is also required to declare the `scalar_data_type` and specify either `ASC` or `DESC`. However, the documentation leaves several questions unanswered:

1. What data types are included under `scalar_data_type`?
2. Does `ASC/DESC` imply that the data is sorted according to its value?

Lastly, is the `SEQUENCE` data type in eXtremeDB supposed to optimize time series management?

Any insights would be appreciated!